# Getting windows store to send Kerberos ticket to Azure AD for SSO

Tags: windows-10, single-sign-on, entra-id

I have managed to get Azure AD Connect Installed, 
I can connect via smart links to office online etc via sso, however, upon logging into Windows 10 for the first time, Users are prompted to login to the Store.

**I was wondering if anyone knows how i would get the Kerberos Ticket Sent to Azure to allow the Windows 10 Store sign in to take place seamlessly? - hence it being called 'Seamless SSO'?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Azure AD doesn't support Kerberos. Also, Have you tried Azure AD join. Then login your device with Azure AD account you can achieve SSO.

Comment: Yes it does. You might want to read up. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-ds/

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso-how-it-works

Comment: Oh , Sorry for my misunderstood. The link you post that  uses Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). Actually, Azure AD doesn't support Kerberos itself. It also need to connect to Local DC.  The figure is very clear answer to your question.